# is it possible to click in the browser to locate the file in vs code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am now using react to develop an app, I was wonder is it possible to click the browser error message then link to the vs code? for example, when the browser show error:

```
ReferenceError: da11111s is not defined
selectMonthListState
src/components/SelectData/index.js:112
  109 | const days = getMonthDay(year, month);
```

I click the `src/components/SelectData/index.js:112` link in the browser, then automatic locate to the visual studio code line.

Comment: Do you have the React developer tools plugin installed in your browser?

Comment: yes, I have installed @Kokodoko

Comment: That would be nice to have! But it's not that complicated to open manually: Copy&Paste the filename, In VS Code Press `Ctrl+P` and paste the filename (it even understands `:112` means the line number and go to that line). See documentation: [VS Code - Code Navigation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_quick-file-navigation)

Comment: I know how to find the code location, but I think if it could locate automatic, it will be nice and more quickly. @Peter Krebs

Comment: Sure, just had to add that comment for completeness. I voted up, hopefully that integration will be a thing.

Comment: VS Code has a debug window, if you start a debug session there, your VS Code window will be linked to the browser running the javascript.